# requirejs alias for module loaded via plugin

Tags: requirejs

I want to create an alias for a requirejs module that is loaded via a plugin, like text or in this case, noext plugin.

Im trying to do this, but when loading resources it will not use the plugin but think of it as a simple path.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        noext: '../../../../Stuff/require/noext',
        resources: 'noext!application/resources'
    }
});
```

How can I create an alias for a module loaded via plugins?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way to alias resources using requirejs is to define them:

```
define('noext', ['../../../../Stuff/require/noext'], function(noext) {
  return noext;
});
```